# While installing FOOMAN SPEEDSTER it Crashes my complete Magento with nginx

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.8 & nginx Server.

I'm installing the following extension [Fooman](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html) And with the following Reference [Guide](http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/InstructionsandTroubleshooting-FoomanSpeedster.pdf) i'm following all steps one by one it is working in my test server(local system) & i did same thing in my Production Server because of that it Crashed complete Magento now i'm not able to see the Admin Panel & Frontend also.

Its showing like this

[image]

What i can do for this to get Back My Site.

I tried to disable that extension from XML files but still i have same errors.

Please help me its a live site.

Answer (score 0):

Manually clear the cache by deleting `var/cache/*` in your site's web folder.

---

In the [relevant guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento#fooman_speedster) it says:

> If you plan on using Fooman Speedster you’ll need to add the following to the server block.
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
> rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
>
> location /lib/minify/ {
>     allow all;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I tried that & restarting nginx Server also still i have same error.